# Looping TextBox Value

Tags: excel, vba

How to add a TextBox value from Userform to many cells of another sheet with looping in VBA.

By looping a string value, how can i get back each character value of that string with vba?

```
Private Sub saveBtn_Click()        
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim staffId As String
    Dim counter As Integer

    FileDir = Module1.copyFilesToTemp(ThisWorkbook.Path)

    staffId = TextBox3.Value

    Set ws = getWorksheet(ThisWorkbook, "TempSheet")
    With ws
        .Cells(3, 26).Value = TextBox1.Text
        .Cells(5, 13).Value = TextBox2.Text

        '// Here is the point I want to get back each character values 
        For counter = 1 To Len(staffId)            
            .Range("M6").Value = Mid(staffId, counter, 1)
            .Range("N6").Value = Mid(staffId, counter, 2)
            .Range("O6").Value = Mid(staffId, counter, 2)
            .Range("P6").Value = Mid(staffId, counter, 2)
            .Range("Q6").Value = Mid(staffId, counter, 2)
            .Range("R6").Value = Mid(staffId, counter, 2)
            .Range("S6").Value = Mid(staffId, counter, 2)
            .Range("T6").Value = Mid(staffId, counter, 2)
        Next

        .Cells(7, 13).Value = TextBox4.Text
        .Cells(16, 1).Value = TextBox5.Text
        .Cells(16, 2).Value = TextBox6.Text
        .Cells(16, 4).Value = TextBox7.Text
        .Cells(16, 10).Value = TextBox8.Text
        .Cells(16, 13).Value = TextBox9.Text
        .Cells(16, 29).Value = TextBox10.Text
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a code request.  It is expected the user puts in an effort to  solve their own problem. Please see [mcve]

Comment: To me it is super unclear what you are trying to do. Especially this: *"I did loop as String and how can I get back each character values?"* • Can you give us an example of your data and how it should look like in the end? Probably a screenshot helps you to explain it better.

Comment: By looping a string value, how can i get back each character value of that string with vba? I mean like that bro sry but i have solved that problem.thz u so much.